# Pulling data from S3 using an address and access key from Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-s3, boto3

I've been given a path to an S3 bucket and a key to access it, how can I access the bucket? and how can I do it from Python?

The name looks like this `solutions/accounts/services` and the key is some string.

I tried doing this:

```py
import boto3

response = client.get_object(
    Bucket='solutions',
    Key='accounts/services'
)

print(response)
```

This yields:

```py
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied
```

I was provided a key to this S3 bucket in the form of : `OKIA4RBSCI236N869IJG`

Where does this key need to be inserted?

Comment: I don't recognize a key starting with `OKIA`. Should it be `AKIA`? Where did you obtain that Key?

Comment: I changed the key contents but it does start with AKIA, just dont wannt put it on the web @JohnRotenstein

Comment: A string starting with `AKIA` is an IAM **Access Key**. It is like a username. It is paired with a **Secret Key** that is like a password. When making API calls to AWS, an Access Key and Secret Key are required. They are normally stored in a credentials configuration file -- the easiest way to create the file is to use the AWS CLI `aws configure` command. Or, if the code is running on an Amazon EC2 instance, you can assign an IAM Role to the instance and credentials will be automatically assigned to the instance. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-sec-cred-types.html

Answer (score 1):

The Key should include all the folders. Example: `accounts/services/file.txt`.

The Bucket name should only be the bucket name. Example: `solutions`.

This will get you `s3://solutions/accounts/services/file.txt`.

Comment: So where would the authentication string go?

Comment: This is your guy @orie! I would recommend using a named profile (Configured it using AWS CLI) if you are in your machine or an IAM role on your cloud-based resources (EC2, Lambda, EB, ECS, EKS) to avoid having to hardcode the secret key and secret key id in your application.

Comment: @orie You did not mention anything about Authentication in your question. If this is relevant, please Edit your question to include details (eg if you are receiving any authentication errors).

Comment: My amazon credentials are stored in ~/.aws, what I mean is that this S3 bucket itself has an authentication key, where would I provide that? it looks like this `UJIAABCJDEFSLH5TX416629G`

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I edittd the question with the relevant details